# Why isnt my program working and how do i stop it from closing real fast

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        int level = 20;
        int age = 30;

        if (age > 21 && level > 10)
        {
            printf ("Congratz you passed!");

            else
                {
                printf ("Nope get out you didnt pass");
                }
        }



    }
```

Please tell me what is wrong i cant seem to figure it out its very basic c++ just cant figure out what is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: your braces are off quite a bit, also this looks more like c code than c++ so Im not sure about the C++ tag, I recommend picking a good intro to C++ book or go through some tutorial online like the ones at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ or both ... gl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i stop it from closing real fast?

You need to add something at the end before you exit `main` that will prompt the user to input something (i.e, `fgetc`, etc.), otherwise it will just run and quit unless you're using a terminal application that is running your program (in that case the terminal app won't quit, and you'll see the output of the app).

Additionally, you need to return an `int` from `main` ... on most platforms successful completion of the program requires that you return `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Close the `if` statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        int level = 20;
        int age = 30;

        if (age > 21 && level > 10)
        {
            printf ("Congratz you passed!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("Nope get out you didnt pass");
        }

        return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're missing both a close-bracket for the first `if` condition, and a return value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Turbo C or an application something like that you need to add `getch()` at the end of main function like this and your braces are completely out of place. Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int level = 20;
    int age = 30;

    if (age > 21 && level > 10)
    {
        printf ("Congratz you passed!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Nope get out you didnt pass");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;

}
```